# Getting strange error using UUID npm module. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, uuid, node-uuid

Getting **"Error: Package exports for 'D:\test\node_modules\uuid' do not define a '.' subpath"** all the time when I *require* it.

OS - Windows 10 Pro
Node version - *v13.1.0*
NPM version - *6.14.4*

I created a project from scratch and run `npm init -y` to create initial *package.json*
Then I installed **uuid** by running `npm install uuid` and created *index.js* with nothing but only

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
uuidv4();
```

from their [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid#create-version-4-random-uuids)

But whenever I try to run this code `node ./index.js` I always get this error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:488
    throw e;
    ^

Error: Package exports for 'D:\test\node_modules\uuid' do not define a '.' subpath
    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:485:15)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:577:20)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\test\index.js:1:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know that Nodejs version v13 had some issues with this.
I tried with v12.16.3 and it's working.
Either use latest v14.2.0 or official LTS v12.16.3

Comment: However weird, it seems to solve the problem for me. Reverted back to Node v12.16.3

Answer (score 2):

Have you been able to resolve the issue?

I'm getting the same result but the only change I made is go from uuid v7.0.3 to v8.0.0. node didn't change, it's v14.1.0 which works with uuid v7.0.3.

I created an issue for it https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/issues/444

Comment: did you try it with v12.16.3?

Comment: no, I did not, I'm keeping node v14.1 as downgrading doesn't seem a solution long-term

Comment: obviously, something is wrong with uuid 8.0.0, but I can't wait for their fix and for me downgrading Node version was the acceptable solution

Comment: I know it's been almost a year since this issue, but I'm having it now using
node: 14.16.3
uuid: 8.3.2

Did any upgrade of uuid fixed it or you just downgrade to 12.16/12.22.1?

Comment: what on earth is wrong with node/javascript when it's this hard to generate a uuid?

Comment: I am using Typescript, for some reason it used to work with `ts-eager`, then I shifted to `esbuild-runner` and I couldn't get it working without downgrading. Might help anyone.